# EaseUS Todo Backup freeze at strartup

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, backup, freeze, easeus-todo-backup

I have bee n using EaseUS ToDo backup trial version for backing up my system for about more than 3 years. So far it has worked well. But recently i downloaded their version 8.3 that is latest version of this time. But when i launch the software, it is completely frozen. Not moving forward. Only splash screen is there and a spinning slide that is showing that program is loading. But when i see task manager or disk indicator for activity, there is no activity.

System Specifications:

- OS: Windows 8.1 Up to Date
- HDD: 500GB RAM: 6GB
- Processor: Core i3 2.6Ghz

[image: Splash screen of stuck EaseUS ToDo Backup 8.3]

An image of stuck splash screen is also attached. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware conflict with the newer version and your hardware.  What made you upgrade to the current version?

Comment: I just wanted to try the latest version. To be up to date

Comment: Moreover i have also checked their system requirements. My system fully meet their system specifications

Comment: Why not ask their support?

Comment: In fact free version has no support

Comment: This behavior is from within Windows or with their boot environment?  If you use a previous version does it work?  Just because you don't receive support with the problem does not mean you cannot ask to see if this is a known issue.

Comment: I can assure you that support *will* want to hear about their program hanging on launch. They may not answer your "How do I do this and that?" questions, but this is essentially a bug report. It will go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question long ago, the issue was resolved in a later version of Easus Todo Backup.